# how to store wsdl preferences on android?

Tags: android, android-preferences

if i am using ksoap2 to call a web service, how can i store the needed preference on android?

i have the following attributes required by ksoap2:

String methodname ;
String url ;
String namespace;
 
String action;

i would like to have the values of these attributes stored in a sort of preference on android, so whenever the user runs the application they get loaded.

I am very new to this kind of stuff, and would appreciate your help

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the properties defined in a file in your project, and load that on startup. If so.. then:

1) Create an `asset/` folder in your project root.

2) Define a properties file, for example ws.properties, and save it in the asset folder. The format must be like the following:

```
methodname=yourMethodNameHere
url=http://your.url.here
namespace=your_namespace_here
action=your_action_here
```

3) Read in the properties file somewhere in your code, something like this:

```
Resources resources = this.getResources();
AssetManager assetManager = resources.getAssets();

try {
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("ws.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

4) Now you can proceed to reference your settings using the properties variable, like this:

```
String methodName = properties.getProperty("methodname");
```

---

Of course, this could be combined with the use of `SharedPreferences`, like others have suggested. You could then perform steps 3 and 4 only the first time your app i started, and insert these settings into the `SharedPreferences`. I guess this would be the cleanest way to do it if you are going to use these settings several places in your code.

Comment: thx a lot man, that was awesome!! can i modify this ws.properties through code 2?

Comment: I don't think that is possible using the AssetManager, actually. The docs say: "This class presents a lower-level API that allows you to **open and read** raw files that have been bundled with the application as a simple stream of bytes."

Comment: Maybe loading the properties file into `SharedPreference` and then using that would be the best option, if you both want to define the properties in a file AND need to make changes to it after install time?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) mechanism, it is an easy way to persist key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in the database 
or create a serializable object with all necessary attributes and save it using a objectoutputstream to sdcard

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly Declare

   private SharedPreferences _pref;
   private String PREFNAME = "ThumbUpChamp";
2. then Write in onCreate()

_pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFNAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

3.and use like this

Editor _edit = _pref.edit();
_edit.putFloat("Qualify1",_wpm);
_edit.commit();